# MSSQL WHERE Function for a Date-Object

Tags: c#, database, stored-procedures

I have a table with a column `id(int)` and a column `HolidayDate(Date)` and I want to get the holidays of a specific month in a list. I know how to do that in code when i got the list with all holidays.

But i want do get the filtered list from the Database(MSSQL Express 2010). Is there a way to filter on a Date-Object in a stored Procedure, when i give the stored procedure the year and the month

For example, this doesn't work:

```
SELECT        Id, HolidayDate
FROM            dbo.Holiday
WHERE        (HolidayDate= '*.11.2013')
```

(Because converting from *.11.2013 to Date-Object does not work)

... and this work:

```
SELECT        Id, HolidayDate
FROM            dbo.Holiday
WHERE        (HolidayDate= '22.11.2013')
```

I just dont want to load a complete list of all holidays and filtering them in my program

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this will get your holidays within a given month:

```
SELECT        Id, HolidayDate
FROM            dbo.Holiday
WHERE         year(holidaydate) = 2013 and month(HolidayDate) = 11
```

Comment: Thank you.. it just works. But just edit your anwser and remove one of the ( in `month((Holiday`. :)

Comment: +1 had answered and deleted answer as had forgotten the exact syntax - thank you entity framework! :-)